# How to create parallax page transition in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create parallax page transition in flutter, where the current page slides up as the new new page slides up. I have seen this kind of transitions used by Spotify, Reddit app or even Samsung native alarm app (seen below).

If anyone have some kind of idea how I could achieve this effect (with code example), I would really appreciate it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this snippet you can run on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b), and take a look at the `SlideBottomUpRoute`, it's the class that manages the transition animation between the pages:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SlideBottomUpRoute extends PageRouteBuilder {
  SlideBottomUpRoute(
      {@required this.enterWidget,
      @required this.oldWidget,
      RouteSettings settings})
      : super(
          transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 350),
          settings: settings,
          pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => enterWidget,
          transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) =>
              Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              SlideTransition(
                  position: Tween<Offset>(
                    begin: Offset.zero,
                    end: const Offset(0, -1),
                  ).animate(
                    CurvedAnimation(
                        parent: animation, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn),
                  ),
                  child: oldWidget),
              SlideTransition(
                  position: Tween<Offset>(
                    begin: const Offset(0, 1),
                    end: Offset.zero,
                  ).animate(
                    CurvedAnimation(
                        parent: animation, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn),
                  ),
                  child: enterWidget),
            ],
          ),
        );

  final Widget enterWidget;
  final Widget oldWidget;
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Navigation Basics',
    home: FirstRoute(),
  ));
}

class FirstRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Route'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Open route'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              SlideBottomUpRoute(enterWidget: SecondRoute(), oldWidget: this),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Route"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('Go back!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the result:

[image: BottomUpTransition]

You can modify the `Offset` in the animations in `SlideBottomUpRoute` to change the way the pages move in the transition.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Exactly what I was looking for :)